# htaccess issue - can't seem to solve it

Tags: .htaccess

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get a simple .htaccess condition and rule to work.  The only way I could get it to work for now was to use literals.  I'm obviously doing something wrong.  Here's a snippet of what is working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://example.com/dir1/dir2/home.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^file1/?$ http://example.com/dir1/dir2/file1.php [L,R=301]
```

When I try to combine these rules into one reg ex rule using RewriteCond to trap errors, I get 403 Forbidden errors.

Does anyone have a proper solution to this I could leverage?

Comment: Can you show the actual code that is causing the problem? (I’m not sure I understand why you want to combine these two lines in the first place?)

Comment: Since these two rules already work, why do you want to combine them? What do you mean by "combine these ... to trap errors"?